# EEPROM emulator on STM32L053

Tags: stm32, eeprom

I known that isn't normal to use EEPROM emulator on a STM32L053, because it has is own EEPROM, but nowadays with the chip shortage, i was forcedto use an alternative MCU (STM32L053R8T6) instead of the "original design" (STM32F030C8T6), so i want to use the same code for both MCU, so the EEPROM emulator on the STM32L053R8T6.
But i'm having some difficulty using the EEPROM emulator on the STM32L053, the compiler didn't give any error, and the code run normmally, but didn't save any value to the EEPROM.

Header File:

```
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_60    ((uint32_t)0x0800F000) /* Base @ of Page 60, 1 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_61    ((uint32_t)0x0800F400) /* Base @ of Page 61, 1 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_62    ((uint32_t)0x0800F800) /* Base @ of Page 62, 1 Kbytes */

/* Define the size of the sectors to be used */
#define PAGE_SIZE               (uint32_t) FLASH_PAGE_SIZE  /* Page size */

/* EEPROM start address in Flash */
#define EEPROM_START_ADDRESS  ((uint32_t) ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_60) /* EEPROM emulation start address */

/* Pages 0 and 1 base and end addresses */
#define PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS    ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + 0x0000))
#define PAGE0_END_ADDRESS     ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + (PAGE_SIZE - 1)))
#define PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS    ((uint32_t)(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_61))
#define PAGE1_END_ADDRESS     ((uint32_t)(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_61 + PAGE_SIZE - 1))

/* Used Flash pages for EEPROM emulation */
#define PAGE0                 ((uint16_t) 0x0000)
#define PAGE1                 ((uint16_t)((PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS-PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS)/PAGE_SIZE)) /* Virtual page nb between PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS & PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS*/


/* No valid page define */
#define NO_VALID_PAGE         ((uint16_t)0x00AB)

/* Page status definitions */
#define ERASED                ((uint16_t)0xFFFF)     /* Page is empty */
#define RECEIVE_DATA          ((uint16_t)0xEEEE)     /* Page is marked to receive data */
#define VALID_PAGE            ((uint16_t)0x0000)     /* Page containing valid data */

/* Valid pages in read and write defines */
#define READ_FROM_VALID_PAGE  ((uint8_t)0x00)
#define WRITE_IN_VALID_PAGE   ((uint8_t)0x01)

/* Page full define */
#define PAGE_FULL             ((uint8_t)0x80)

void EE_ReadData(void);
uint16_t EE_Init(void);
uint16_t EE_ReadVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t* Data);
uint16_t EE_WriteVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t Data);

#endif /* __EEPROM_H */
```

EEPROM Write Variable Function:

```
uint16_t EE_WriteVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t Data)
{
    uint16_t Status = 0;

    /* Write the variable virtual address and value in the EEPROM */
    Status = EE_VerifyPageFullWriteVariable(VirtAddress, Data);

    /* In case the EEPROM active page is full */
    if (Status == PAGE_FULL)
    {
        /* Perform Page transfer */
        Status = EE_PageTransfer(VirtAddress, Data);
    }

    /* Return last operation status */
    return Status;
}
```

Comment: Writing to a Flash requires two step: first erase the sector of the flash, then program the data. Did you do implement this way ?

Comment: Also, how are we suppowed to help since we don't have the whole code ?